# Creating a Map with String, Object combination

Tags: apex, soql, list, map, bulkification

I have a List of String. This list consist of accountNumbers from Account Object. `List<String> accountNumList`. I have a child object `XYZ__c`, which is child of Account Object. `XYZ__c` object has a custom field called `status__c` and `flag__c`

I am looking at an efficient way to build a Map of type `Map<String,String>`. where Key is the `accountNumber` and Value is the `status__c` field of the child object of the corresponding Account. There could be multiple children of a account. I need to get only the child whose `flag__c` field has 'Active' text in it and use it as the value.

What I think I should do to build this Map:

```
List<String> accountNumList; // has all the accountNumbers
List<Account> acc =[select id,accountNumber,(select id,status__c,flag__c from child_relation__r where flag__c=='Active') from Account where accountnumber in:accountNumList];

Map<String,String> accountMap = new Map<String,String>();
For(Account a : acc){
accountMap.put(a.accountNumber,a.child_relation__r.status__c);
}
```

Is this an efficient way to build the Map? Any Suggestions!

Comment: You could still have more than one child with that flag value, no? You still have to consider what to do in case of collision as this scenario is described.

Comment: There can be only one child with active flag.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to index into your list. Before you do so, however, you have to check if the list is empty.

```
for (Account record : [/*query*/])
{
    if (!record.Children__r.isEmpty())
        accountMap.put(record.AccountNumber, record.Children__r[0].Status__c);
}
```

If you omit the empty check, than any iteration over a record without an active child would throw this error:

> System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Comment: The isEmpty() check is to prevent Null Pointer Exception?

Comment: @SfdcBat If the child list were null, that check could not possibly prevent a null pointer. It's so you don't get `System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0`.